# Why am I getting an NGINX 502 error when connecting to my docker container

Tags: nginx, devops

I have been trying to setup a subdomain on a separate droplet for my website. I'm using docker-compose and when connecting directly to the ***http://ip:port*** everything looks correct, however when connecting through the subdomain, I am running into issue after issue. This is the closest I've gotten and I need some help getting past this last little bit.
Here is my setup

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./cloudflare:/etc/cloudflare


  wordpress:
    image: *image*
    container_name: wp
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: DB_NAME
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: PREFIX
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: DB
      MYSQL_USER: USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORDw
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid       /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
  upstream web {  
    ip_hash;
    server wp:8000;
  }
  server{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *subdomain* *server_ip*;
    ssl_certificate /etc/cloudflare/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/cloudflare/key.pem;
    if ($scheme = "http") {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    } 
    location / {
      proxy_pass https://wp;
    }
  }
  include        /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type   application/octet-stream;


  log_format     main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


  access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile       on;

  keepalive_timeout 65;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

If I change the proxy_pass to "http://wp" Rather than "https://wp" I get a "too many redirects" error. I've been hitting my head against a wall trying to figure this out. DevOps is not my forté and I'm new to it so if anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it!

**NOTES:
I have verified that the db home and site urls are the correct subdomain and scheme
I have adjusted all urls in the site to be the correct subdomain and scheme

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while using Alpine as image.

Ended up having to change conf.d to http.d which was stated in the documentation [here](https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.14.0-released.html):

> NGINX package changed the default directory for the vhost configs from /etc/nginx/conf.d to /etc/nginx/http.d